# Youtube Data API V3 - How do you get comments for a single video? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have tried searching everywhere to find something to help with implementing comments from a single youtube video into an android application. I already have the Youtube Data API v3, got my api key sorted, and got the link for my get function which I got from Google's API explorer. But I am now stuck on how to get the JSON data from that link into the application. If anyone has any idea on how to do this or could link me to something to do this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Add the library through gradle](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3). I believe the API explorer uses the REST based api, which you'd to make http requests within Android studio to use.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't know how to actually build the functions in order to use the api. I have done everything prior to that, put the jar files in the lib folder, added to library, all that, but it's just the coding im getting confused on as I've never done it before

Comment: I haven't done it before with the Java library either, but you should be able to work off the [samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java) as a base.